# Zend_Http_Client SSL Exception

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, nginx, zend-http-client

I have **Zend Framework 1.12** project, and **PHP 5.5.3** and **nginx 1.2.7** + **php-fpm** installed on Ubuntu 10.04 server.

I receieved the following exception

`Message: Unable to Connect to ssl://pftradingnet.com:443. Error #179898264: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`

from `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->connect`  function.

My configure command is

`'./configure' '--enable-opcache' '--prefix=/opt/php' '--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pgsql=/usr' '--with-tidy=/usr' '--with-curl=/usr/bin' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-xsl=/usr' '--with-ldap' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-iconv-dir=/usr' '--with-snmp=/usr' '--enable-exif' '--enable-calendar' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--with-mcrypt=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-zip' '--with-pear' '--with-libdir=lib' '--with-config-file-path=/opt' '--enable-fpm' '--with-fpm-user=fpm' '--with-fpm-group=fpm' '--enable-debug'`

It worked fine previously on **php5.3+Apache2**, what can be the cause of error?

Comment: Install/enable `mod_ssl` check your php.ini.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen `mod_ssl` is apache's thing, isn't it?

Comment: I'm assuming there will be a `mod_ssl` for other webservers. You've configured it with `openssl`, figure out how to enable it.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen it is `configure` command for PHP, not for web-server.  But why I need SSL extension on Web server if I am retrieving data from remote server from my PHP-script via Zend_Http_Client?

Comment: Because PHP uses the socket transport from your webserver.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen No, I switched from php-fpm to apache2 and it does not work. But before it was working well with the same Apache configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was that I light-mindedly copy-pasted `cofigure` command script from [here](http://www.brandonsavage.net/compiling-php-5-5-from-scratch/).

I have recompiled PHP with `--with-openssl` instead of `--with-openssl-dir=/usr` and it works well now.